# How to pass 2 values in .render() to Handelbars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass multiple values into `res.render` to be passed into my handlebars template. It seems to fulfil the condition but it doesn't show the content.

I'm trying to show a special navbar and a users snippets (their data) if they're logged in. Otherwise I want to display my normal navbar and all snippets (data from all users).

I've got it working if I just hand in a single value, but I can't seem to hand in multiple values.

Express code:

```
 router.route('/')
.get(function (request, response) {
if (request.session.name) {
  Snippet.find({ user: request.session.name._id }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    data.forEach(function (element, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
    let context = {
      snippets: data.map(function (snippet) {
        return {
          _id: snippet._id,
          user: snippet.user,
          title: snippet.title,
          body: snippet.body,
          createdAt: snippet.createdAt
        }
      })
    }
    response.render('home/index', {loggedIn: true, context: context}) //Here is the issue
  })
  }
```

Handlebars template:

```
<ul class="people_list">
    {{#if loggedIn}}
        {{!-- Logged in --}}
        {{#each snippets}}
            <h2><i class="star fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{title}}</h2>
            <h4>{{ createdAt }}</h4>
            <pre>
                <code class="language-javascript">{{body}}</code>
            </pre>
            <hr />
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        {{!-- Not logged in --}}
        {{#each snippets}}
            <h2><i class="star fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{title}}</h2>
            <h4>{{ createdAt }}</h4>
            <pre>
                <code class="language-javascript">{{body}}</code>
            </pre>
            <hr />
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @sasuri, are you saying that it works when you pass in just one item (context) but not when you pass in the loggedIn variable as well?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what npm package you're using? There are multiple express handlebars modules (express-handlebars, express-hbs, etc).

Comment: I'm using express-secure-handlebars. Yes it works only when passing(context)

Comment: can you also tell me whether `loggedIn` is working properly and what the format of the `context` object is when you debug it? Is it an array itself or does it have sub-objects?

Comment: context is just an array, loggedIn is working just fine. Both working fine separately.

Comment: Change `{{#each snippets}}` to `{{#each context}}`. You've named the object `context` not `snippets` if context is just an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in an array called `context` but referring to it as `snippets` in the handlebars code.

Either change your handlebars template to called `{{#each context}}` or change your nodejs code to `response.render('home/index', {loggedIn: true, snippets: context})`.